# Is there some way to "group" Rectangle, Eliipse, Text, etc to use them together

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating graphics editor like Inkscape. For now I am using specific "check" (as shown down) for each tool, this means I have to write all the code twice or more (as shown down).

I somehow want to make it only for one tool and then use it. Is it possible?

```
public void ChangeGraphicsValues()
{

    if (activeTool == Tools.Rectangle)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rect.Count; i++)
        {
            #region Width
            if (objectWidthBox.Text != "")
            {
                rect[i].Width = Convert.ToDouble(objectWidthBox.Text);
            }
            else
            if (objectWidthBox.Text == "")
            {
                objectWidthBox.Text = "0";
            }
            #endregion

            #region Heigth
            if (objectHeightBox.Text != "")
            {
                rect[i].Height = Convert.ToDouble(objectHeightBox.Text);
            }
            else
            if (objectHeightBox.Text == "")
            {
                objectHeightBox.Text = "0";
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        if (activeTool == Tools.Text)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count; i++)
            {
                #region Width
                if (objectWidthBox.Text != "")
                {
                    txt[i].Width = Convert.ToDouble(objectWidthBox.Text);
                }
                else
            if (objectWidthBox.Text == "")
                {
                    objectWidthBox.Text = "0";
                }
                #endregion

                #region Heigth
                if (objectHeightBox.Text != "")
                {
                    txt[i].Height = Convert.ToDouble(objectHeightBox.Text);
                }
                else
                if (objectHeightBox.Text == "")
                {
                    objectHeightBox.Text = "0";
                }
                #endregion
               //some other things - rotation,...
            }
        }
    }
```

`rect` is a List of Rectangles from graphics, txt is a List of TextBoxes. Those tools are meant to be used for creating some graphics like in Inscape.

I want them to be creatable, changable (editable), destroyable. I can say I have everything, but I want them to be accesible together like `obj.Height` instead `rect.Height` and `txt.Height` or shorten my code

Comment: I'd suggest making `rect` and `txt` inherit from the same base class, or implement the same interface, but since you didn't show us what they are there is no way to tell you how to do that.

Comment: (rect is a List of Rectangles from graphics, txt is a List of TextBoxes) Those tools are meant to be used for creating some graphics like in Inscape or... I want them to be creatable, changable (editable), destroyable. I can say I have everything, but I want them to be accesible together like obj.Height instead rect.Height and txt.Height or shorten my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle and TextBox are both derived from FrameworkElement base class. Width and Height properties are declared in FrameworkElement. So you can extract all duplicating code to method:

```
private void UpdateFigure(FrameworkElement figure)
{
    figure.Width = Convert.ToDouble(objectWidthBox.Text);
    figure.Height = Convert.ToDouble(objectHeightBox.Text);
}

public void ChangeGraphicsValues()
{
    // validate input values before using them
    if (objectWidthBox.Text == "")
    {
        objectWidthBox.Text = "0";
    }

    if (objectHeightBox.Text == "")
    {
        objectHeightBox.Text = "0";
    }

    if (activeTool == Tools.Rectangle)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rect.Count; i++)
        {
            UpdateFigure(rect[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (activeTool == Tools.Text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count; i++)
        {
            UpdateFigure(txt[i]);
        }
    }
}
```